# Almost- and non-primes in the Ulam spiral

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, visualization

There are lots of [explanations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral#Explanation) of the preferred  diagonal distribution of prime numbers in the [Ulam spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral):

[image]

I wonder if these explanations can also explain the observation that when highlighting also "almost-primes" – i.e. numbers $m$ with large enough [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(m)$ (for prime numbers $p$ we have $\varphi(p) = p-1$) – a checkerboard pattern emerges:

[image]

Note that the values of $(\varphi(m)+1)/m$ are indicated by different shades of gray, and only numbers $m$ with $(\varphi(m)+1)/m \geq 0.52$ are highlighted.

Note also, that the only numbers that disturb the visible checkerboard are

- false positive: $2,4,8,16,32$ (but not $64, 128, 256$)
- false negative: $105,165,195,255,285$

This is, how the spiral looks like when all numbers are displayed:

[image]

Note that – of course – also numbers $m$ with a small value of the totient function $\varphi(m)$ ("almost non-primes") tend to be arranged along diagonals:

[image]

(Only $m$ with $(\varphi(m)+1)/m \leq 0.48$ are highlighted.)

Comment: My first observation when looking at your so-called "checkerboard pattern", is that you've mostly colored the odd numbers, which obviously give that pattern.

Comment: Ulam spiral seems to me to be the search for patterns that do not actually exist. The main issue is : How do we even define "pattern" ?

Comment: @Henrik: Thanks a lot for this hint. It gave rise to this [follow-up question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320451/when-is-2-varphin-n-and-how-to-prove-it) - let's see if an answer is given there.

Comment: @Peter: I disagree. Patterns **do** exist and they **are** meaningful, as can be possibly seen [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320451/when-is-2-varphin-n-and-how-to-prove-it)

Comment: What about the definition of a "pattern" ? Can it be defined rigorously ? If not, we cannot claim that the prime numbers exhibit a pattern. We can find a (local!) structure that APPEARS to be a pattern, but when we go to larger primes, this pattern will almost surely vanish anyway.